# Rally rest API when updating user story fails with "Desired release is not in project scope for story" error

Tags: rest, api, rally

I'm trying to update Rally's user story with Release value when no release value is set.

I'm using .Net Rally Rest API to do this. It works for majority of user stories (like 4000 of them). There are few where it runs into the following error.
"Desired release is not in project scope for story"
When trying to update.

For some userstories,  I noticed they were child stories with Parent user story does not have release value. Not sure if it matters though. There are some that are normal user stories but still fails with the same error.
Need help in identifying what is causing this issue thrown by Rally Rest API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Epic stories (stories with children) are not schedulable in releases or iterations, but I don't think that's what you're running into here.  Most likely the stories that are failing are in a different project and you're attempting to set the release to a release from another project.

When iterations and releases are created there's a little checkbox to create "like" iterations/releases for each project in the hierarchy:

[image]

So each project will have its own "Iteration 1" with the same start and end dates.  You just need to make sure you're setting each story's release to the corresponding release in that project and you should be good.

Comment: Kyle, Yes I'm getting the release scoped to that project and using the project specific release to set the release for that user story. It works for most cases. But fails randomly for a few user story. I tried to get the pattern for user story that it is failing. based on my observation so far it is child user story or story whose parent does not have a release set. Are there likelihood that when a parent does not have release set, any children under the parent cannot be programmatically set with a release? Any thoughts? - Vasanthi